# HTML tables $variable[$row['column']] = array()

Tags: php, html, datatables

I converted an application from MySQL to PDO and am trying to figure out what a line of the below code is doing. This code takes data from a MS SQL DB and puts it into a table (only part of the code is posted). Can anyone tell me what the `$overtime[$row['employee_id']."_".$date]['details'] = array("eid"=>$row....` line of code (I believe line 7 of the below code) is doing? I see that `['details']` is referenced in the table data code, so is this somehow grouping the data together? It looks like employee_id and date is somehow being grouped, as I can only see 1 overtime entry per employee per date. I tried removing the `$row['employee_id']."_".$date` and `['details']`, but keep getting undefined array key errors for each `<td>` (id, date, eno, badge, name, etc.).

My application uses datatables for some features, so not sure if this is part of that feature? I cannot find `['details']` defined anywhere. I need to remove the code that is grouping `employee_id` and `.$date` together, and use the table ID instead (tried simply replacing that arrays/variables with $row['id'], but got the undefined variable error I mentioned above in the `<td>` sections).

```
<tbody>
<?php
    $att=$conn->query("SELECT a.*,e.employee_no,e.badge, concat(e.lastname,', ',e.firstname,' ',e.middlename) as ename FROM overtime a inner join employee e on a.employee_id = e.id order by datetime_log asc  ") or die(mysqli_error());
    $lt_arr = array(1 => "Time and One Half",2=>"Double Time+");
    while($row=$att->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['datetime_log']));
        $overtime[$row['employee_id']."_".$date]['details'] = array("id"=>$row['id'],"eid"=>$row['employee_id'],"name"=>$row['ename'],"eno"=>$row['employee_no'],"badge"=>$row['badge'],"acceptedqty"=>$row['acceptedqty'],"rejectedqty"=>$row['rejectedqty'],"npqty"=>$row['npqty'],"nochangeqty"=>$row['nochangeqty'],"date"=>$date);
        if($row['log_type'] == 1 || $row['log_type'] == 2){
            if(!isset($overtime[$row['employee_id']."_".$date]['log'][$row['log_type']]))
            $overtime[$row['employee_id']."_".$date]['log'][$row['log_type']] = array('id'=>$row['id'],"date" =>  $row['datetime_log']);
        }else{
            $overtime[$row['employee_id']."_".$date]['log'][$row['log_type']] =array('id'=>$row['id'],"date" =>  $row['datetime_log']);
        }
        }
        foreach ($overtime as $key => $value) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date("M d, Y",strtotime($overtime[$key]['details']['date'])) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['eno'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['badge'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['acceptedqty'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['rejectedqty'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['npqty'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['nochangeqty'] ?></td>
    <td>
        <div class="row">
            
    <?php 
    $att_ids = array();
    foreach($overtime[$key]['log'] as $k => $v) :
     ?>
     <div class="col-md-10" style="">
        <p>
            <b><?php echo $lt_arr[$k] ?>
        </p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary edit_overtime" data-id="<?php echo $overtime[$key]['details']['id']?>" type="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger remove_overtime" data-id="<?php echo $key ?>" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is the `undefined array key errors` a **Warning** type ? (please check the error message again)

Comment: Yes, it is a Warning type, but no data is shown in my data table.

Comment: I think I got the data to finally show up in the table how I intended. Turns out I had to remove the ['details'] completely from all lines of code, then make some additional minor changes. I'm still curious as to what that line of code is (an array of an array?) for future reference.